# Uninstall SEP using powershell in batch file

Tags: powershell

I use this powershell script to uninstall Symantec Endpoint Protection and when the resultvalue is 0, I want it to reboot the computer itself or else display the error code (returnvalue) as is. Anyone can help !

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name='Symantec Endpoint Protection'" -ComputerName . ).Uninstall()
```

[image]

REVISION to use REG QUERY to uninstall

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\currentversion\public-opstate' -Name DeployRunningVersion"') do (
Set DeployRunningVersion=%%a%%b%%c)

If  "%DeployRunningVersion%" lss "1445427" (
```

Comment: [Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software. Alternatives Inside!](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/).

Comment: What will be the correct uninstall script after using REG QUERY to check if old version is installed then uninstall it. (See my revision) ?!

Answer (score 0):

your script should look like this:

```
$uninstall = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name='Symantec Endpoint Protection'" -ComputerName . ).Uninstall() | select ReturnValue
if ($uninstall -eq '0' )
{
write-host (get-date -format s) " return value is 0"
shutdown /r /t 00
}else { 
write-host (get-date -format s) " return value is $uninstall"
}
```

this will select the ReturnValue and store it in a variable called uninstall, and then it will check this variable, if it has 0 it will reboot immediately because we set /t 00. if the value is anything else other than 0 it will just display it.